# Detecting zoom event in ScrollView for React Native

Tags: react-native

I would like to implement pinch zoom functionality for the image view in React Native.

I'm starting by wrapping an  element in a  element. I would like to detect the zoom event and then scale the image accordingly.

How do I get the zoom event?

Answer (score 1):

If an Image is wrapped by ScrollView, when ScrollView zooms, the Image will zoom too.

And the 'onScroll' function of the ScrollView will detect the zoom event too.